# Navparam passed data are not available in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In login page application will get `UDI` and `Token` and if login/registration is successful it will pass to MapPage:

```
if (Token != "-1")
                   {                  
                this.navCtrl.push(MapPage, {UDI: this.UDI, Token: Token})
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(MapPage);
                this.navCtrl.popToRoot;
```

in construct method before `popToRoot` fires`console.log(this.UDI, this.Token);` shows the value of them but after that they are undefined.

```
this.UDI=this.params.get('UDI');
this.Token=this.params.get('Token');    
console.log(this.UDI, this.Token);
```

update 1: the result
[image]

as you can see before going to map page it shows the right passed values

```
map.ts:39 2NYIRWI0N8Z6HW2M3HWR XWRU441NHH0B9GSHVC3P
```

but after navigation root page changing

```
map.ts:39 undefined undefined
```

Comment: u need certain variables to be declared globally and then u may transfer your UDI and token to all other pages.

Comment: hi @devanshsadhotra do you know any reference guide to session making and management instead of using local storage or native storage?

Comment: u won't need a local storage for the above scenario. all you need is two variables, which you can access throughout the project

Answer (score 1):

Your keys look like variables rather than string literals.So your key and value *are both* values of UDI and Token.

Try with quotes.

```
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(MapPage, {'UDI': this.UDI, 'Token': Token})
```

Also you are doing both `push` with params and then `setRoot` without params. Your map page is set  as root *without* params.
[setRoot](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#setRoot) function also takes params

Comment: why are you doing push *and* setRoot? do one.. I think it is doing set root where no parameter is passed

Comment: because map page is main page and there shouldn't be back button.

Answer (score 1):

> because map page is main page and there shouldn't be back button.

Just like @suraj says, you're pushing the view with parameters, and then setting the same page as root but without parameters. That's not correct. If you don't want to show the back arrow, just set the page as root

```
if (Token != "-1") {                  
    // this.navCtrl. push(MapPage, {UDI: this.UDI, Token: Token}) <- don't do that
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(MapPage, {UDI: this.UDI, Token: Token}); <- send the data like this
    // this.navCtrl.popToRoot; <- don't do that
    // ...
}
```